# Add a tooltip to a given cell in AG grid react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, ag-grid

I would like to add a tooltip to a given row in my AG Grid, I have found the following field that can be added to the ColDefs `tooltipField` but I would like this tooltip to be a custom string, rather than a field.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: what do you mean by "I would like this tooltip to be a custom string, rather than a field"? Sounds like you may need to create your own custom tooltip component.

Comment: Rather than using a field as the message shown in the tooltip, I would like to add in some other text, is using a custom tooltip the only way you think this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tooltipValueGetter` property on the column defs. This field takes a callback function which should return the string to display in the tooltip.

[Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/column-properties/#reference-columnsOnly).